# Get rid of the trailing comma (PHP)

Tags: php

The very last line is where it's not working. I can't figure out what should go there instead of `$post`.

```
    if (isset($_COOKIE["WP-LastViewedPosts"])) {
    //echo "Cookie was set.<br/>";  // For bugfixing - uncomment to see if cookie was set
    //echo $_COOKIE["WP-LastViewedPosts"]; // For bugfixing (cookie content)
    $zg_post_IDs = unserialize(preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", stripslashes($_COOKIE["WP-LastViewedPosts"]))); // Read serialized array from cooke and unserialize it
    foreach ($zg_post_IDs as $value) { // Do output as long there are posts
        global $wpdb;
        $zg_get_title = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = '$value+0' LIMIT 1");
        foreach($zg_get_title as $post) {
            echo "<a href=\"". get_permalink($value+0) . "\" title=\"". apply_filters('the_title',$post->post_title) . "\">". apply_filters('the_title',$post->post_title) . "</a> \n"; // Output link and title
            echo implode(', ', $post);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Need to elaborate on *how* it's not working. Show the output of `$post`.

Comment: Looks to me like you don't need that line at all.

Comment: I'd like to show the comma after links, except for the last one. 

With the above, it doesn't show the comma at all.

Comment: Some more background: this is part of the last-viewed-posts Wordpress plugin. Originally there was a list, and I'm attempting to output this as one line, with each link separated by a comma.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comments, one way of doing this:

```
foreach ($zg_get_title as $post) 
{
    $title = apply_filters('the_title', $post->post_title);
    $posts[] = '<a href="'.get_permalink($value).'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a>';
}

echo implode(', ', $posts);
```

Comment: FYI the snippet of code posted in the original question is __HORRIBLE__

Comment: Hi @Matt Humphrey, your code shows the commas correctly, but repeats the post listing twice.